# Is this really a cross join?

Tags: mysql, sql

I was inspecting the SQL produced by a Java ORM tool (Hibernate) and came across this odd query.  It initially stood out because of the CROSS JOIN.  But it also seems to use ANSI-89 JOIN syntax in the WHERE clause.

```
SELECT max(c.item)
FROM ItemPubStatus c 
   CROSS JOIN TargetSystemPub t 
   CROSS JOIN Item m 
WHERE c.targetsystempublication = t.id 
   AND c.canonicalitem = m.id 
   AND t.targetsystem = ?
   AND m.datapool = ?
   AND m.itemtype = ?
```

1. Considering the join in the WHERE clause, is this really a CROSS JOIN and will it produce a cartesian product?
2. Although this SQL was generated for MySQL, this app supports several database vendors?  Can I expect most databases to treat this query the same way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this really a "cross join"?

The question is rather meaningless.  SQL is not a procedural language.  A SQL query describes the *results* from processing, not how the processing is accomplished.

The `WHERE` clause is describing filtering on the full Cartesian product of the tables.  The filtering is equivalent to equi-joins.  The syntax is not the best way of expressing the query.  But almost any query optimizer (including MySQL) is going to implement this in a more reasonable way than generating the Cartesian product and filtering the result.